# React Native VirtualList key extractor value in child component

Tags: react-native

How can I set the key manually inside a child component from a `FlatList`? The reason I need this is because all my children have `Modal`s and I'm returning an array in `render()`.

```
<FlatList
    key={'partner-list'}
    data={_.values(this.props.partners)}
    renderItem={({item}) => <Card item={item} />}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id ? item.id.toString() : 'no id'}
/>
```

Card.js render()

```
render(){
        return(
            [
            <Modal key={'partner-modal-???'} />,  <--- here
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={???}                         <--- and here
                onPress={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(true);
            }}>
                ...
            </TouchableOpacity>
            ]
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're passing in the `item` as a prop, so you should be able to use a unique field from the `item` in your Card.js render?

```
render(){
        return(
            [
            <Modal key={`partner-modal-${this.props.item.id}`} />,  <--- here
            <TouchableOpacity
                key={`${this.props.item.id}`}                       <--- and here
                onPress={() => {
                this.setModalVisible(true);
            }}>
                ...
            </TouchableOpacity>
            ]
        )
    }
```